# Issue with Android studio 3.5 indexing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I am not able to sync my project properly.

[image]

Does anyone face the same issue? Is it related to databinding. I am using this in my project.

`dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }`

.

Comment: This is an ongoing issue happening on the latest version 3.5. The issue is with finding the correct path of the launcher activity starting from the package root. I am not sure but it may be related to databinding according to the stacktrace.